# i am having an error "out of memory error" i have tried all solutions but i am stuck with that error

Tags: ios, sqlite

```
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"contact.db"]]; 

NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:databasePath]== NO)
{
    const char *dbpath = [self.databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)           
    {           
        char *errMsg;
        const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PERSON  (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, PASSWORD TEXT,EMAIL TEXT)" ;

    if (sqlite3_exec(contactDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK){
        theStatus.text = @" FAILED TO Table created";
    }
    sqlite3_close(contactDB);

} else {
    theStatus.text  = @"Failed to OPEN/create database";
}}
[filemgr release];
```

I am using above code and i have already tried `sqlite3_open_v2` but i am stuck with problem.

Please help.

Comment: So, when you step through the above code, where does it fail?

Comment: ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:databasePath]== NO) it fails at this statment

Comment: Please quote the EXACT error message, and also obtain and include the exception stack trace.  If you don't know how to get the exception stack trace, learn how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two instances where you encounter **out of memory** error if you've ignored opening the database or if the database reference used appeared to be nil.

Please put a break pointer at the following line of code

```
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
```

and check if the above if block is executed, if it is not then you know the culprit.

Comment: no same error is appearing.i have already used your recomendation

Comment: Does the if block get executed?

Comment: if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)

Comment: after that if block is not executing

Comment: yes, does it get executed?

Comment: Then there is something wrong with two parameters you have passed across, dbpath or contactDB. Please check if both of them refer to non nil object.

Comment: I am using above mentioned code.in that code parameters you have specifed do not refer to null object.

Comment: ldindu please help me

Comment: does if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:databasePath]== NO) executed?

Comment: no it does not execute.

Comment: what is the purpose of "if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:databasePath]== NO)"?